# # in a CakePHP $this->Html->link

Tags: php, cakephp

I was wondering how I go about adding a "#" to a cakephp url without it being escaped. Ive tried 'escape' => false but to no success. I am doing this to try and link to a id="comments" section of the page that has contains the comments. Here is my code for the linking:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['total_comments'].' comments', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $post['Post']['slug'].'#comments'),array('class' => 'comments-icon')); ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['total_comments'].' comments', array(
       'controller' => 'posts', 
       'action' => 'view', 
       $post['Post']['slug'], 
       '#' => 'comments' //Or #comments only without key
      ), array('class' => 'comments-icon'));
```